# Find and Replace powershell script not functioning, not sure where else to go

Tags: powershell, automation

I am fairly new to powershell scripting, so please bear with me. I am trying to write a script that looks for a legacy vulnerability id inside a column on a csv, and then looks inside a sub directory at some other powershell scripts, matches the legacy ID number on the scripts inside of that subdirectory, and replaces them with the new vulnerability ID from the first column on the csv. I probably did not explain that very well but I can eleborate. Below is what I currently have

```
**$list = Import-csv -Path .\Downloads\test.csv
Foreach($PSScript in (Get-ChildItem -Path .\Downloads\Scripts -Filter "*.ps1" -Recurse)){
    $contents = Get-Content -Path $PSScript.FullName -Raw
    foreach($item in (($list.Legacy -split ";").trim())){
    if($contents -match $item){
    $contents.Replace($item,($list.'Vuln ID'[$list.Legacy.IndexOf($item)])) 
    Write-Host $contents
    }
   }
 }**
```

and this is the output

```
**$GroupID = "V-44745"
$Hostname = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
$Title = "Google Chrome Current Windows STIG"
if ($Hostname -eq $null){
$Hostname = $env:computername}
$Configuration = ""
$Regkey = (Get-ItemProperty Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome").AllowOutdatedPlugins
if ($Regkey -eq '0'){
    $Configuration = 'Completed'}
    else{
    $Configuration = 'Ongoing'}
$Audit = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name GroupID -Value $GroupID
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hostname -Value $Hostname
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Configuration -Value $Configuration
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Title -Value $Title
$Audit**
```

The $Group ID above is the value that I am trying to change

I do not know how to add the csv values in just text and keep the formatting,
I tried, but here is a picture [CSV Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy5cj.png)

So my goal is it should change $GroupID = "V-44711"  to  $GroupID = "V-221558". I think because I am splitting $item it is not finding it in the array.

I tried what TheMadTechnician suggested, and for some reason it started creating empty lines continuously at the end of the script. I changed

Write-Host | Set-Content

to

```
Write-Host $contents
```

just to display something else.

It returns with

```
$GroupID = "V-44711"
$Hostname = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
$Title = "Google Chrome Current Windows STIG"


if ($Hostname -eq $null){

$Hostname = $env:computername}

$Configuration = ""
$Regkey = (Get-ItemProperty Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome").AllowOutdatedPlugins
if ($Regkey -eq '0'){
    $Configuration = 'Completed'}
    else{
    $Configuration = 'Ongoing'}



$Audit = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name GroupID -Value $GroupID
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hostname -Value $Hostname
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Configuration -Value $Configuration
$Audit | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Title -Value $Title
$Audit
```

I have also tried something like this

```
 ForEach($Vuln in $List){
        ($Vuln.Legacy -split ";").trim() | ForEach-Object {if($contents -match $_){$contents -Replace $_,$Vuln.'Vuln ID' | Out-Null;Write-host $contents;Write-Host $_}}
```

It seems to be finding the value in the legacy column just fine. The replace seems to not be working

Shoutout to TheMadTechnician for setting me on the right path. My second attempt worked I just forgot to set $contents in the second half. If TheMadTechnician comments back, I would still very much be interested in finding out why that didn't work. this was my Solution

```
$list = Import-csv -Path "Downloads\test.csv"

Foreach($PSScript in (Get-ChildItem -Path "Downloads\Win10-STIG-Audit" -Filter "*.ps1" -Recurse)){
    $contents = Get-Content -Path $PSScript.FullName -Raw
    ForEach($Vuln in $List){
        ($Vuln.Legacy -split ";").trim() | ForEach-Object {if($contents -match $_ -and $_ -notmatch "null"){$contents.Replace($_,$Vuln.'Vuln ID') | Out-File $PSScript.FullName; break}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, because you're splitting the value it's not finding it in the array. But I think there's a better way to do this! My suggestion is to use RegEx to do the replace, and build your matching pattern per updated vuln. Something like this:

```
ForEach($Vuln in $List){
    $Legacy = ($Vuln.Legacy -split ';' | ForEach-Object {[regex]::escape($_.trim())}) -join '|'
    $Updated = $Contents -replace $Legacy, $Vuln.'Vuln ID'
    $Updated | Set-Content $PSScript.FullName
    Write-Host | Set-Content
}
```

What that does, is the first line in the CSV it will look at the Legacy column, split it on the semicolon, then for each item in that it will trim the string, and escape it for a RegEx search, then join all strings from the split with a pipe. That comes out looking like this:

```
V-44711|SV-57545
```

The way that works in a `-replace` is that it will match on either V-44711, or SV-5745, and replace it with `$Vuln.'Vuln ID'` (the updated value). Since we're splitting within the `ForEach`, and including the entire object not just one property we can reference other properties more easily.

**Edit:** The above is dumb, and won't work. It's seriously writing the file each time it loops through each Legacy. So even if it finds and updates the item it will just overwrite it with the old contents on the next loop iteration. Solution to that is to change `$Updated` to `$Contents`, and probably move the output to after the loop.

```
ForEach($Vuln in $List){
    $Legacy = ($Vuln.Legacy -split ';' | ForEach-Object {[regex]::escape($_.trim())}) -join '|'
    $Contents = $Contents -replace $Legacy, $Vuln.'Vuln ID'
    Write-Host | Set-Content
}
$Contents | Set-Content $PSScript.FullName
```

Comment: Thank you very much TheMadTechnician! I will give that a go and let you know if it works

Comment: I tried what you suggested and edited my post with the results